# Steps to run a lua project from the github

Tags: lua, torch

I am new to lua, and want the entire steps to run a lua project which is in github. Please let me know what I need to install and what are prior steps to run the project?

Comment: Which Lua project?

Comment: @cyclaminist I am guess that the project is torch, it is one of the tags. with that said what type of system are you looking to run the project on?

Comment: Yea sorry torch project. its something to do with human pose estimation. However, now i have figured it out to install torch and luarocks. But i am stuck with installation of cuda. any leads on that ? like installation steps?